# Getting data in specific time

Tags: java, android, time

I have This method that getting data from network.

```
    RssParser parser =new RssParser(INPUT);
    AdapterItems adapter = new AdapterItems(parser.getItems(), MainActivity.this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I want to getting data for example in maximum 3 second and if in 3 sec method failed to pass data return false value or something like this.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your current thread (thread A) launch a thread to get data (thread B).
2. When B finishes, it updates some A field and notifies A (so it can wake up).
3. A waits for 3 seconds.
4. After waiting (either if 3 seconds passed or woken up) check field and return the appropriate value.

PS: consider using exceptions to signal errors/exceptions instead of returning booleans from methods.

Comment: What part exactly is unclear? Please note that I'm assuming you already know the basics of multi-threading in Java.